# Make a dll color picker default for paint/etc?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, notepad++, colors, dll

I found [this color picker DLL](http://pscolorpicker.codeplex.com/releases/view/48812) file online which is similar to the Photoshop's Color picker.
Normally on other applications including ms paint, the color picker is very old and that's the reason I was looking for a differnt alternative.
Currently I'm using [HIDEIT](http://vasanrulez.deviantart.com/art/HideIt-Hide-all-your-windows-206517834) tool to minimize the demo form of the color picker to system tray for opening per requirement time...

The dll site autohr mentions that the dll can be used to be called from other programs, but didn't say anything about how to call it from other programs etc..? I tried installing it in default copy paste way on Notepad++ plugins directory, but that didn't work. Notepad++ said something about ANSI and UTF8 plugins mismatch in an error popup.

My question is: Can I use this dll to be made default for any program calling windows default color picker like paint etc?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the windows 10 default color picker](https://superuser.com/questions/1412770/how-to-change-the-windows-10-default-color-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the author mentions other programs, he's talking about programs written by you. This DLL is designed to be used by somebody creating a new app that needs a colour picker. You can't easily change an existing binary like Paint to use this instead.